# Typing a CodeMirror instance living at an inline template variable

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Playing with CodeMirror in an Angular2 app (TS).

I have this code `<codemirror #editor />`, which gives me the following easy access to the ElementRef:

`@ViewChild('editor') editor: any;`

However, the CodeMirror instance itself lives deeper at `this.editor.instance`, so I use:

`this.cmirror = this.editor.instance;`

to configure editor options from the UI using CodeMirror API (`this.cmirror.setOption('...')`);

Everything works just fine as long as I use type `any` on the ViewChild reference. I have downloaded the [typings file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/codemirror/codemirror.d.ts) though:

`/// <reference path="../../typings/codemirror.d.ts" />`

and now any attempt to use an explicit type fails.

I tried: `@ViewChild('editor') editor: ElementRef` - but `.instance` does not exist there, so I am getting errors in IDE.

What would be then the correct way of strongly typing the ViewChild reference for such a inline template reference pattern?